# How to change elements of an Adapter from outside?

Tags: android, gallery

I have a *gallery* with a `custom adapter`. I'm showing an image along with some texts and buttons.

I want to change the texts that are associated with the images *when the corresponding buttons are clicked*.

If I put the button handler inside the adapter, it doesn't catch the call.

I found out that I should moved the handler to the activity.

But the problem is that I don't have access to the Adapter anymore. Any solutions?

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter { ...


MyGallery myGallery = (MyGallery) findViewById(R.id.mygallery);
myGallery.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, ...));
```

Comment: `If I put the button handler inside the adapter, it doesn't catch the call.` , are you used the `button.setOnclickListener` to the adpater? the `onclicklistner` should works.

Comment: @idiottiger: I put <Button android:onClick="handler" ... in the xml layout which I used to design my adapter with.

Comment: so in your `Activity` you have a `public void handler()` method?

Comment: if you config the event process in the xml, you should process in the activity, so the `myGallery.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, ...));` need init in the activity, here you can save the adapter's instance in the activity.

Comment: Create a method public void updateElement(int position, Object newValue) in you MyAdapter implementation, then call the method from outside to update the value, i.e. myAdapter.updateElement(1, newValue);

Comment: @yorkw: how do I get the position?

Comment: @techiServices it's public void handler(View view).

Comment: In your Activity how are you setting the adapter? I assume with setAdapter()? In that case why don't u get your adapter anywhere in the activity using getAdapter() provided your gallery is a global variable. And once u have the adapter then I guess you could change based upon your requirement. Maybe I am missing the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the OnClickListener in the getView function of the adapter. When you inflate the view you can make a call to findViewById on the view to get a reference to the Button. You can then set the OnClickListener on the Button object itself.

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
MyGallery myGallery = (MyGallery) findViewById(R.id.mygallery);
myGallery.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, ...));
```

into your `Activity`

Oh yeah and make a member reference to the `Adapter` eg `MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(....`